# Any specific code to view one Beamer frame containing all overlayed frames and the points where they overlap?

Tags: beamer, overlays, slideshow, overlap

a pretty meta-question for Beamer but I can provide details if needed.

Basically when I overlay sub-frames in one frame using the /pause command, I get multiple additional frames in my PDF viewer on Overleaf, which makes the overall slideshow very messy very fast because of dozens of successive slides.

I wanted to know if there was a way to view all overlayed sub-frames as one frame in the PDF viewer, possibly displaying the points of overlap between each sub-frame to check whether all the desired pause commands have been used.

Comment: Hello, you are probably looking for the `handout` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found with the "handout" option